# Request a select option in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I am looking for a possibility to include a select option in a database. For some reason the value doesn't show up in the POST function of the sound_upload.php. I always get the mysql message "category can't be null". Is this problem connected to the use of the jascript or did I simply use the wrong php code?

**Upload.php**

```
    <?php
    require_once('auth.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>My Profile</title>
<link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./../../src/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./../../src/jquery.relatedselects.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $("#categories").relatedSelects({
        onChangeLoad: 'datasupplier.php',
        selects: ['categoryID', 'subcategoryID']
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload</h1>
<a href="profile.php">My Profile</a> | <a href="upload.php">Upload</a> | <a href="http://www.soundypedia.com/index.php">Logout</a>
<p>
<form action="sound_upload.php" method="post" id="categories" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table align="center">
                <tr valign="baseline">
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Title: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="title" value="" size="32" /></td>
                </tr>

                    <tr valign="baseline">
                            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Category: </td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="categoryID">
                                    <option value="">Category</option>
                                    <option value="Natural">Natural</option>
                                    <option value="Urban">Urban</option>
                                    <option value="Musical">Musical</option>
                                    <option value="Abstract">Abstract</option>
                                    <option value="Signals">Signals</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="baseline">
                            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Subcategory: </td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="subcategoryID">
                                    <option value="">Subcategory</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                    </tr>

                <tr valign="baseline">
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Keywords: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="keywords" value="" size="32" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Upload: </td>
                        <td><label>
                        <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" />
                        <?php   // Configuration - Your Options
                            $allowed_filetypes = array('.mp3','.mid','.m4a'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the valartistation.
                            $max_filesize = 5242880; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 5.0 MB).
                            $upload_path = './../../sounds/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).
                            $filename = $_FILES['upload']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
                            $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

                                // Upload the file to your specified path.
                            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))?>
                        </label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" /></td>

        </table>
        <div id="hide">
            <input type="text" name="artist" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']; echo ' '; echo $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'];?>"/>
            <input type="hartistden" name="date" value="<?php echo date("d.m.Y"); ?>" />
            <input type="hartistden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" />
        </div>

</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**sound_upload.php**

```
<?php require_once('sound_database.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? textval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO sounds (id, title, artist, category, subcategory, keywords, upload, download, rating, ip, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['artist'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['category'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['subcategory'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['keywords'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_FILES['upload']['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['download'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['rating'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ip'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['date'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_test, $test);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $test) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<?php
$Anzahl = mysql_affected_rows();
    if ($Anzahl>0)
    {
      echo 'Your sound upload has been successful!<br>To go back click <a href="upload.php">here</a>';
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'An error has occured! Your upload has not been saved.<br>To go back click <a href="upload.php">here</a>';
    }
?>
<link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your select box is posting `categoryID`, not `category`.

```
<select name="categoryID">
  ...
</select>
```

Update your server-side code accordingly and you should be golden:

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['categoryID'], "text"),
```